# The Test.isRunningTest() function is not working

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I am using `if(Test.isRunningTest())` condition to set the response code to 200 for code coverage related to my HTTP callout class, so that the success scenario gets covered. But in the coverage details screen, I can see that this function isn't getting covered at all and I am not sure why.

I am adding my callout class code with the screenshot of the coverage screen below. Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
global class fileUploadCallout {
    @future(callout=true)

    global static void Push_to_OB(String body, String boundary, String apiEndPoint, String sfOrderId)
    {   
        OBIntegrationSF__c ins         = OBIntegrationSF__c.getValues('MainConfig');
        String epURL                   = ins.ApiBaseUrl__c;
        String apiURL                  = ins.ApiKey__c;
        HttpRequest request            = new HttpRequest();
        Http ht_tp                     = new Http();  
        HttpResponse response          = null;
        String strMailText;
        
            
        try {              
            system.debug('file blob request akki '+ body);
            request.setEndpoint(epURL+apiEndPoint);      
            request.setBody(body);
            request.setHeader('Authorization', apiURL);
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            request.setMethod('POST');
            request.setTimeout(120000);
            
            System.debug('This is the future request sent akki ' + request);

            response = ht_tp.send(request); 

            System.debug('STATUS:'        + response.getStatus());
            System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'   + response.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('RESPONSE_BODY:' + response.getBody()); 

            // sending mail on success

             if(test.isRunningTest()) {
            //     response = new HttpResponse();
            //     response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //     response.setBody('{"success":true,"code":200,"message":"SUCCESS","data":"Updated","validationErrors":null}');
                 response.setStatusCode(200);
             }

            if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                strMailText = '';
                strMailText += '<div>Hi, <br/> <br/> The IO file synced successfully from SF to OB for the SF Order ID: </b>' + sfOrderId + '<br/>' +
                                                '<br/> You can check the Order record '+ 
                                                '<a href="'+ URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+sfOrderId+'">here</a><br/><br/> Thank you';
                strMailText += '</body></html>';

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.toAddresses = new String[] { 'avasut@test.com' };
                message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
                message.subject = 'IO File Synced Successfully from SF to OB for Order Number ' + sfOrderId;
                message.setHtmlBody(strMailText);
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
            } else {     
                throw new MyException(response.getBody());
            }
            
            System.debug('success akki ' + response);
            
        } catch(System.Exception e) {   

             //Sending mail on failure

            strMailText = '';
            strMailText += '<div>Hi, <br/> <br/> The Syncing of IO file from SF to OB failed for the SF Order ID: </b>' + sfOrderId + '<br/>' +
                                        'Error was: ' + e.getMessage() +  '<br/> You can check the Order record ' +
                                        '<a href="'+ URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+sfOrderId+'">here</a><br/><br/> Thank you';
            strMailText += '</body></html>';

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.toAddresses = new String[] { 'avasut@test.com' };
            message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
            message.subject = 'IO File Syncing from SF to OB failed for Order Number ' + sfOrderId;
            //message.plainTextBody = strMailText;
            message.setHtmlBody(strMailText);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
            
            System.debug(e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

Code Coverage Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code in test execution is failed at line `response = ht_tp.send(request);`. Because you have `try-catch` block, which catches exceptions, you were not able to observe this exception during test execution.

You have to use [HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) for testing callouts, instead of `Test.IsRunningTest()`

The example from the documentation:

**Callout class:**

```
public class CalloutClass {
    public static HttpResponse getInfoFromExternalService() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://example.com/example/test');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**CalloutMock class:**

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('http://example.com/example/test', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
        
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

**Callout test class:**

```
@isTest
private class CalloutClassTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
        // Set mock callout class 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        
        // Call method to test.
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
        HttpResponse res = CalloutClass.getInfoFromExternalService();
        
        // Verify response received contains fake values
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"example":"test"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

The key moment here is in callout test class:

`Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());`

After setting this mock in test, when callout class will get to the point of sending the request `HttpResponse res = h.send(req);` apex framework sets response to what is returned by callout mock class `respond` method.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll use the Httpcalloutmock interface instead of the Test.isRunningTest() as you suggested.